# The Beasts in Daniel 7

Tags: daniel, beast

We know that the 4th beast is Rome, first part historical Rome, and later part  *it had ten horns* future revised Rome.

Doesn't the ten horns represent the same thing the ten toes on the metallic image in Daniel 2 represent? 10 future kings (5 from the West/5 from the East) who will give their power to the Antichrist? The little horn in Daniel 7 the Antichrist, and he comes out of the Seleucid empire of what was once Alexander the Great's dynasty?  Would make the Antichrist Islamic, and the false prophet out of Rome (mix of iron and miry clay)?  Doesn't the tree stump in Daniel 4, with the bands of iron and bronze prophetically show us that the Roman and Grecian empires will be involved in the final world empire that will be led by the Antichrist?  A mix of the two?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please take our tour to find out what we look for in questions, and how to show evidence of your own research.  As it stands, you are asking six questions and that is why you need to be more specific.  https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

We do not need to look so far into the future to discover whom Daniel spoke of as the "little horn" (8:9) or the one who brings the "abomination of desolation." (11:31) Many commentators hold that the Book of Daniel was written in support of the Maccabean Revolt in the 2nd century c.e. and that it goes no further in its historiography than the time of Antiochus IV Epiphanes. For example the [Expositor' Bible Commentary](https://www.studylight.org/commentaries/eng/teb/daniel-7.html) says that the book is:

> well adapted to inspire the hopes and arouse the heroic courage of the persecuted Jews in the terrible days of Antiochus Epiphanes... The interests of every other Hebrew prophet are always mainly absorbed, so far as earthly things are concerned, in the immediate or not-far-distant future. That is true also of the author of Daniel, if, as we have had reason to see, he wrote under the rule of the persecuting and blaspheming horn.

If this is true, then the idea that the "anti-Christ" - a term not used in the book - is "Islamic" must be ruled out. The evil "horn" is most likely Antiochus himself, who literally carried out the "abomination" mentioned in 11:31.

> Raging like a wild animal, he set out from Egypt and took Jerusalem by storm. He ordered his soldiers to cut down without mercy those whom they met and to slay those who took refuge in their houses. There was a massacre of young and old, a killing of women and children, a slaughter of virgins and infants. In the space of three days, eighty thousand were lost, forty thousand meeting a violent death, and the same number being sold into slavery. (2 Maccabees 5:11–14)

Using Antiochus IV as our historical marker and working back:

- The first great beast is Nebuchadrezzar and the Babylonian Empire.
- The bear is the Median Empire
- The leopard or panther represents the Persian kingdom.
- The terrible fourth beast with four heads represents Alexander the Great and his successors, including ultimately Antiochus IV.

Attempting to find explanations in a distant future long after the time when the Book was written is not necessary. We need look no further than Antiochus Epiphanes.

Comment: Unfortunately, antiochus does not fit the bill here...I have studied him at length and there are quite a number of significant problems with that theory...for one he did not expand his kingdom...quite the oppsit happened actually and also, he fell embarrassingly subservient to the Romans contrary to the prophecy in Daniel.